# Intermittently getting status 400 for JS/CSS/Images after upgrading to Tomcat 9.0.80

Tags: java-8, tomcat9, http-status-code-400

We use Java 8 with JDK8 and our current tomcat version is v8.5.78
After upgrading to Tomcat 9.0.80, the webpage is not rendered correctly as some JS/CSS/Images are throwing HTTP Status 400. If we reload the browser it works fine.
Has anyone faced this issues?

We have tried adding cachingAllowed=false in context.xml but no luck.